# In a WinForms menu is there a way to batch update

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, menu

I build some dynamic context menus in my app with code like:

```
mi = new ToolStripMenuItem( caption ) { Tag = c, Enabled = true };
context_menu.Items.Insert( n, mi );
mi.Click += new EventHandler( ContextClick);
```

This works well. However, if the number of items is large (say 1000) it can take minutes to build the menu. I realise 1000 items in a menu is unusual but the issue here is the speed. For combo- and list-boxes there is a BeginUpdate() / EndUpdate() that can be put around this sort of operation. Is there a mechanism for menus?

'similar' code runs in a VB6 project and it takes less than 10 seconds to perform the operation.

Comment: There is the [`Items.AddRange` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h1fb63bz(v=vs.110).aspx). I would expect that if you create your items first and then add it in one `AddRange` call, the performance goes up.

Comment: There is AddRange but that adds to the bottom of the menu. I need to insert.

Comment: I have tested your conditions (executing this code 1000 times) and it takes less than 30 seconds; in any case, there shouldn't be any (noticiable) difference with respect to VB6. Post more relevant parts of your code such that we can help you further (method where this code is called, for example).

Comment: I build four of these menus (two are context and two go into the MDI Parent) - so it is four lots. The loops are literally four sets of above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the context_menu.Items.CopyTo method to copy the current menu in to a buffer. Then clear the current collection with context_menu.Items.Clear(). Update the buffer as necessary in the order you wish (doesn't trigger UI updates) and then use AddRange(buffer) to put them back.

Sample code:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

var items = new ToolStripItem[menuStrip1.Items.Count];
menuStrip1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

var itemList = new List<ToolStripItem>(items);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    itemList.Insert(2, new ToolStripMenuItem { Text = "Hello" + i.ToString() });

menuStrip1.Items.Clear();
menuStrip1.Items.AddRange(itemList.ToArray());

sw.Stop();
label1.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
```

47 milliseconds on my cruddy machine.

Comment: That looks interesting - I will give this a go

Comment: That solution works just beautifully @SimonGoldstone. Thank you (all) for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. There are a number of components within the  .net framework that don't have suitable Begin/EndUpdate methods, so double buffering is a good choice for these. Cheers.